# Returned TS observable is undefined, except when it isn't

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a patch request that looks like this:

```
patchSharingStatus(id: string): Observable<Idea> {
        return this.http.patch<Idea>(this.ideaApiUrl + '/' + id + '/sharing', {});
    }
```

It hits my API, and my API returns an object with two fields inside it, one called `sharingEnabled` and the other called `sharingLink`.

I'm consuming `patchSharingStatus()` here:

```
    toggleSharing(id: string) {
            this.bigIdeaService.patchSharingStatus(id).subscribe(res => {
                const oldItemIndex = this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.find(item => item.parentIdeaId === res.bigIdeaId).parentIdeaId;
                console.log('oldItemIndex', oldItemIndex);
                console.log('oldItem', this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.find(item => item.parentIdeaId === res.bigIdeaId));
                console.log('res.sharingEnabled', res.sharingEnabled);
                console.log('res.sharingLink', res.sharingLink);
                // The below line is (view.page.ts:81) from the below stack trace.
                this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex].sharingEnabled = res.sharingEnabled; // <== This is (view.page.ts:81) from the below stack trace.
                this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex].sharingLink = res.sharingLink;
            });
        }
```

In my browser console, I see the below:

```
oldItemIndex 58832ca4-ef93-4aa5-a670-83dc4384c306
instrument.ts:129 oldItem {sharingEnabled: true
sharingLink: "http://localhost:8100/sharing/item/df5a3bb0-8c46-4c4c-a70a-37a3465fe62b" ...}
instrument.ts:129 res.sharingEnabled true
instrument.ts:129 res.sharingLink http://localhost:8100/sharing/item/65a27b76-b65f-4dfe-b013-0b1a9c8254db
instrument.ts:129 TypeError: Cannot set property 'sharingEnabled' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (view.page.ts:81)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:265)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:207)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:139)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:89)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.ts:101)
    at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.ts:162)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (innerSubscribe.ts:30)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at CatchSubscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:139)
    at CatchSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.ts:162)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (innerSubscribe.ts:30)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr.ts:215)
    at XMLHttpRequest.sentryWrapped (helpers.ts:87)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:429)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28500)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:428)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:200)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:511)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1651)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1688)
```

This error would indicate to me that the response data printed above does not contain a field called `sharingEnabled`, or maybe it does, but it's null. This is not the case. I've checked the response from the API and it's good, and I can see above that these values are populated correctly.

I can even see in my front end that the returned data is being displayed!

What gives? This is an annoying error and I'd like to get rid of it. Can anyone help?

Edit:

To add more context here, I've got an angular component rendering the data.
One component is created for each item in an array (it's a list of ideas).
Each of these components has an idea passed into it from a parent page.
Each component has an emitter that triggers a method in the parent page of the component - and this is method calls `patchSharingStatus()`.

`toggleSharing()` is also in the parent. `this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails` is in the parent as well, this is the array that drives all of the components. `toggleSharing()` takes the response from the API and modifies the item the response pertains to, and I am then relying on that change to cause the child component to re-render (React does something similar - is this the way it works?)

Edit 2:
Per Nicholas_Jones I have added an if statement to check `oldItemIndex` for null.

Here's the updated version of `toggleSharing`:

```
toggleSharing(id: string) {
        this.bigIdeaService.patchSharingStatus(id).subscribe(res => {
            const oldItemIndex = this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.find(item => item.parentIdeaId === res.bigIdeaId).parentIdeaId;
            console.log('oldItemIndex', oldItemIndex);
            console.log('res.bigIdeaId', res.bigIdeaId);

            if (!this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex]) { console.log('im undefined'); }

            this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex].sharingEnabled = res.sharingEnabled;
            this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex].sharingLink = res.sharingLink;
        });
    }
```

and the new stack trace:

```
oldItemIndex 9360d92d-e04c-4069-872d-dca880d9f1eb
instrument.ts:129 res.bigIdeaId 9360d92d-e04c-4069-872d-dca880d9f1eb
instrument.ts:129 im undefined
instrument.ts:129 TypeError: Cannot set property 'sharingEnabled' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (view.page.ts:82)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:265)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:207)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:139)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:89)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.ts:101)
    at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.ts:162)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (innerSubscribe.ts:30)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at CatchSubscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:139)
    at CatchSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.ts:162)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (innerSubscribe.ts:30)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr.ts:215)
    at XMLHttpRequest.sentryWrapped (helpers.ts:87)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:429)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28500)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:428)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:200)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:511)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1651)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1688)
```

Unfortunately, the null check is triggered, but prints AFTER I've printed oldItemIndex and seen that a value is there!

So maybe this is some kind of race condition?

Comment: this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex] might be undefined. You can add a check ```if(!this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex]) console.log('im undefined');```

Comment: Your question doesn't give enough information to form a solution. I believe your issue has to do with  accessing an array? with ```58832ca4-ef93-4aa5-a670-83dc4384c306``` which is possible if it's a object property/key

Comment: Nicholas_Jones have updated my question in response to your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to troubleshoot a situation like this...

```
toggleSharing(id: string) {
  this.bigIdeaService.patchSharingStatus(id).subscribe(res => {
    const oldItemIndex = this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.find(item => item.parentIdeaId === res.bigIdeaId).parentIdeaId;
    console.log('oldItemIndex', oldItemIndex);
    console.log('oldItem', this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.find(item => item.parentIdeaId === res.bigIdeaId));
    console.log('res.sharingEnabled', res.sharingEnabled);
    console.log('res.sharingLink', res.sharingLink);
    // The below line is (view.page.ts:81) from the below stack trace.
    this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex].sharingEnabled = res.sharingEnabled; // <== This is (view.page.ts:81) from the below stack trace.
    this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex].sharingLink = res.sharingLink;
  });
}

Error:
instrument.ts:129 TypeError: Cannot set property 'sharingEnabled' of undefined
...
```

What this error is saying is that the interpreter cannot run the line

```
this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex].sharingEnabled = res.sharingEnabled;
```

If you were to comment this line then you would get the same error for the following line as well.

I'm suprised you were not recieving some form of Typescript warning and normally it should show a 'possibly undefined' warning.

To add some additional logic to assist in detecting if the object is undefined would look like this

```
if (this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex]) {
  this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex].sharingEnabled = res.sharingEnabled; 
  this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex].sharingLink = res.sharingLink;
}
```

or

```
this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex]?.sharingEnabled = res.sharingEnabled; 
this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex]?.sharingLink = res.sharingLink;
```

The next troubleshooting step if these lines are not being ran, check and fix oldItemIndex.

Since, their are multiple ways your data could be structured I couldn't form a solution giving the information in your question but, the code could have been correct if your data was structured as follows and you were accessing object properties/keys.

```
activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails = {
  58832ca4-ef93-4aa5-a670-83dc4384c306: {
    sharingEnabled: "someValue",
    sharingLink: "someValue"
    ...etc
  },
  58832ca4-ef93-4aa5-a670-83dc4384c307: {
    sharingEnabled: "someValue2",
    sharingLink: "someValue2"
    ...etc
  },


}
```

the code

```
this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex].sharingEnabled = res.sharingEnabled;
```

Would then be accessing the property/key but, I assumed this is not how your data was structured.

I assumed your data was structured more like this...

```
activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails = [
  0: {
    sharingEnabled: "someValue",
    sharingLink: "someValue"
    ...etc
  },
  1: {
    sharingEnabled: "someValue2",
    sharingLink: "someValue2"
    ...etc
  },
]
```

Which would mean you were trying to access a number based index with a string UID. This could return a object that was undefined due to incorrect indexing.

After seeing your feedback this was in fact the case and by switching from the UID value to the index of the object containing the matching UID using the Array.Prototype.find() method has solved your problem.

```
const oldItemId = this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.find(item => item.parentIdeaId === res.bigIdeaId).parentIdeaId;

const oldItemIndex = this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.indexOf(this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.find(item => item.parentIdeaId === res.bigIdeaId));
```

Answer (score 2):

Nicholas_Jones if you post this answer I'll credit you with it.

I've realised I had a logic error.

```
const oldItemId = this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.find(item => item.parentIdeaId === res.bigIdeaId).parentIdeaId;

const oldItemIndex = this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.indexOf(this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.find(item => item.parentIdeaId === res.bigIdeaId));
```

Before, I was referring to `oldItemId` - which is a string UUID as above.
Then I was trying to log the item at the index of that id - which makes no sense, and so `array.prototype.find()` found nothing as you would expect.

I've changed the reference to `oldItemIndex` as above - thick takes the item found by `array.prototype.find()` and then grabs the index of it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Can you please make console.log(this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails[oldItemIndex]) only to be sure about the data, and send me the stacktrace. Also a console.log of this.activeProjectAndAssessmentDetails.length and oldItemIndex